# Python Pandas: how to pass "views" of DataFrames into function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My scenario is that a function should be able to modify the values inside a `pandas.DataFrame`. But I don't want to expose the whole DataFrame to the function, just the parts that needs to be modified. A reason for this transparency is that the function will be more general w/ the ability to specify which portion of the DataFrame to be modified from outside. Imaging I can write a function `mult(df_view, a)` which multiplies all the values in the view by `a`. Notice that I don't want a new DataFrame to be created. The value change should be *in-place*.

This is my attempt:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[1,1]])

def mult(df_view, a):
    df_view *= a

mult(df.loc[1,1], 2)

print(df)
```

This is the (undesired) output:

```
   0  1
0  1  1
1  1  1
```

The expected output is:

```
   0  1
0  1  1
1  1  2
```

Notice that if we do the assignment directly (i.e. w/o the function), it works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[1,1]])

df.loc[1,1] *= 2

print(df)
```

... gives:

```
   0  1
0  1  1
1  1  2
```

So, apparently I'm messing up something when passing that view through the function call. I have read this [blog post from Jeff Knupp](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) and I think I understand how python's name-object binding works. My understand of DataFrames is that when I call `df.loc[1,1]` it generates a proxy object which points to the original DataFrame w/ the `[1,1]` window so that further operations (e.g. assignment) goes to only elements inside the window. Now when I pass that `df.loc[1,1]` through the function call, the function binds the name `df_view` to the proxy object. So in my theory, any change (i.e. `df_view *= a`) should be applied to the view and thus the elements in the original DataFrame. From the result, clearly that's not happening and it seems the DataFrame is copied in the process (I'm not sure where) because some values were changed outside the original DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Just check

```
>>> type(df.loc[1, 1])
numpy.int64
```

So evidently this isn't going to work - you're passing in a single immutable int, which has no bind to the outer DataFrame.

Were you to pass in an actual view with simple indexing (mutable construct), it would *most likely* work.

```
>>> mult(df.loc[:, 1], 2)
>>> df
    0  1
0   1  2
1   1  2
```

But some other ops will not work.

```
>>> mult(df.loc[:, :1], 2)
>>> df
    0  1
0   1  2
1   1  2
```

All in all I think this control flow is a bad idea - a better option would be to operate directly on the index as you showed works. Pandas tends to be more friendly (IMHO) when you stick to immutability when possible.

Comment: The data being `numpy.int64` doesn't mean the value in the DataFrame cannot be assigned to. In fact it did in the case of `df.loc[1, 1] *= 2`. As you have pointed out, the logic of when/why passing a "view" into the `mult()` function will work is a bit unclear. This isn't a definite answer (though helpful in the sense that you pointed out some successful and failure cases).

Comment: @Roy Python passes by assignment, and when you directly use `df.loc[1, 1] *= 2` you are assigning to an _element_ of that DataFrame still, and not the actual value which is passed to the function. [This is a good read](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in in some case which is sometimes [difficult to detect](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html), copy of data are made.

You can get round the difficulty by indexing in the function :

```
def mult(df,i,j,a):
    df.loc[i,j]*=a

mult(df,1,1,2)
mult(df,1,slice(0,2),6)
print(df)
```

for

```
   0  1
0  1  1
1  6 12
```

Comment: While your suggestion should work, it is exactly what my question was trying to avoid (i.e. having the protocol of passing view coordinates into the function and the function only access the specified section of the DataFrame). Thus I cannot mark this one as an answer.